# Precompile Multilingual ASP.NET pages server side

Tags: asp.net, multilingual, iis-8

We have developed an asp.net 4.5 web application that has been translated into 36 different languages.

We are using standard .aspx pages and controls with associated resource files for each of the 36 different languages.

The VS project is compiled before published to create the main binaries and resource file binaries for each language. (Bin and .aspx files)

The problem is when we first deploy the site it takes over 10 minutes for the server to compile all web pages. It seems that each page is being compiled 36 times (once for each language).

We are using Windows Server 2012 and IIS8 compiles each page into the following location using conhost.exe:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

As there are over 100 pages x 36 languages - the site takes a while to compile and startup.

The compile process only happens once when the site is initially deployed or after updates when a user first hits the page. Once all pages are compiled, the site functions lightening fast - pages are never compiled again unless changed.

I am wondering if there is any way to precompile the pages on the web server before setting the site live and waiting for the user to hit a page?

Here is a screenshot of the web server resource monitor as it crunches all pages when a user first hits the site:

[image: Resource Monitor]

The server executes **conhost.exe** multiple times (each page x each language) to compile the .aspx pages into the **Temporary ASP.NET Files** directory.

I realize this behaviour is by design, but it would be great if there was a way to get it to compile all pages on the site without having to set the site live first.

Comment: Have you set any default language for your project? I presume that you pre-compile site and publish means build and publish only aspx pages and dlls.

Comment: Yes the default language is English. Yes, I build the project and publish the bin and aspx files.

Comment: Are the resource file embeded one or served as content?

Comment: Resource files are located in App_LocalResources folders in the format page.aspx.resx and page.aspx.LANG-CODE.resx. The build action is set to 'Content'

Comment: Can you try by setting it to embeded?

Comment: I tested setting all resources files to embedded (creating bin assemblies for resources) but it didn't improve speed of initial compile by IIS.